# Генерация rtf/doc файла из имеющейся информации хранящейся в БД

Tags: android, rtf

Есть инфа которую необходимо сгенерировать в документ .rtf или .doc мыслей как это сделать пока нет, может подскажете способы, мб библиотеки есть какие-то?

Comment: В прошлом тысячелетии были разные прожекты генерации (в том числе и) rtf из SGML/XML: DSSSL, TEI Lite и пр.

Answer (score 1):

на stackoverflow.com основная масса постов ссылается на библиотеку [POI Apache](http://poi.apache.org/), хотя я сам ниразу ей не пользовался.

небольшой [пример](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/SimpleDocument.java) как создать документ.

[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13535394/1233682) на оригинальный пост на стеке, там есть еще примеры исходников

Answer (score 0):

Изучи формат http://www.codenet.ru/progr/formt/rtf1.php и сгенерируй сам, там не сложно. Сам сталкивался с такой задачей, мучился с поиском библиотек для генерации doc формата, правда на PHP, потом решил сгенерить сам RTF - не так трудно оказалось.

Comment: а как русские символы записывать?
в 16 коде не вариант(